# Automatic Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: html, css, button, scroll

This will sound very "noob", but I'm new to HTML/javascript/php, and so far I've been having a blast discovering new stuff. Right now though, I'm having a minor problem.

I'm trying to make a UI with lots of buttons (it's a matrix of buttons, 5x24). When the browser is maximized, it's all good, the buttons are where they're supposed to be. But when the browser is adjusted so that it becomes narrower (width becomes smaller), the buttons try to remain visible by moving on top of each other.

I want to know how to make it so that a horizontal scroll bar automatically appears.

I've tried putting everything in a `<body>` tag and putting `style="width:100%;overflow:scroll;"` but the buttons still do what they do, and that is, ending up on top of each other when they're supposed to be side by side...

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, `width: 100%` means the full width of the parent element. Give your container the necessary width (in `px`, not `%`) to accomodate all your buttons. Than put that in a div with `overflow: auto`, and it should work.

Comment: Holy Fudge! You're a genius! Haha. Thanks!

Comment: No so much. My answer was missing the extra wrapping div part. I just edited the last sentence to add that (but you probably figured that out already, since it seems to be working now).

Comment: Oh. I didn't, actually. It just automatically scrolled when I changed the width to a specific number of px. Hehe. I'm not sure why... I just enclosed everything in a body tag...